# Simple harmonic motion in a horizontally accelerating lift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator

How would the time period of a pendulum in a lift be if the lift was accelerating horizontally to the right ?  My teacher did it by putting a pseudo force "ma" to the left, then getting the resultant of that and mg then substituted for g in the T equation as (a+g)^1/2 (power half) I'm not sure whether that is correct. Have tried drawing FBD but get confused over which force's are balanced. If somebody could explain along with an FBD explanation that'd be really helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: Time period of what are you concerned about? A pendulum in the lift?

Comment: Imagine rotating your frame of reference so that 'down' is along the vector $\vec{a}+\vec{g}$. Then you just apply standard SHM equations to a (pseudo)gravity of magnitude $\sqrt{a^2+g^2}$ (which is not exactly the same as what you've written).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time period of a pendulum when a constant horizontal force acts](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234104/)