# if a building sways because of a constant wind will it sway back past its equilibrium

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, building-physics

If I have a building that acts analogous to a spring at equilibrium and a constant wind comes from the north forcing the building to sway to the south will the building ever sway back towards the north past its equilibrium point.

Comment: Where is the question here I mean if you have already considered building to be analogous to spring then just find out the answer to your question using spring

Comment: Perhaps a homework question asking to consider the fundamentals of how a spring (or pendulum) work?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it would or would not do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. It will not swing back past its *original* equilibrium position.

The oscillating building is like a vertical mass on a spring. The wind is like gravity exerting a constant force on the mass. When there is no wind this is like there being no gravity, or no load on the spring ($m=0$). When the wind blows at constant speed this is like gravity being switched on, or a load being suddenly attached to the spring. The mass falls and then oscillates *about a new position of equilibrium* which is not the natural length of the unloaded spring.

If there is no dissipation of kinetic energy, the mass goes back up to the same height it started, but no higher. If there is no energy lost due to air resistance the building swings back as far as its initial position where it was when the wind started, but it would not go back any further than that, while the wind continues blowing.

If the wind stops then the building continues oscillating, but now about the *original* position of equilibrium.

To summarise : (i) a change in wind speed sets the building oscillating, (ii) the new wind speed determines the new equilibrium position.

See also [Time period of a pendulum when a constant horizontal force acts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234104).

Comment: Any reason for down-voting?